# Connection must be valid and open. Error on MySql 5.2

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I have this error at the call af stored procedure... Why?

```
    public void InsertVideo()
    {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AxWaveConnection"].ToString());
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("InsertVideo", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("in_youtubevideoid", VideoId));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("in_title", Title));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("in_rating", ViewCount));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("in_viewcount", Rating));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: I believe you need a `conn.open()` somewhere before you execute the `cmd`.

Comment: You really should be using the `using` statement or properly closing and disposing of the connection.

Comment: Actually, according to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html) you should work with `MySqlHelper` instead of working with `MySqlCommand` objects directly with open/close.

Answer (score 3):

because you forget to `OPEN` the connection, before calling `ExecuteNonQuery`, call `conn.Open()` first,

```
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Your complete solution

    public void InsertVideo()
      {
         MySqlConnection conn = new  MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AxWaveConnection"].ToString());

         MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("InsertVideo", conn);

        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("in_youtubevideoid", VideoId));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("in_title", Title));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("in_rating", ViewCount));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("in_viewcount", Rating));

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
```